# Insert at specific 'ID' into my table.

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to write a PHP script using a database for school. Since my MySQL skills are currently dying, I would like to ask following question:
Following problem: I need to insert 'upload' at a specific 'ID' into my table. It should make something like this: 
insert into PHP_Project() where ID = ;

```
$pdo = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password, $this->pdoAttributes);
$statement = $pdo->prepare('insert into PHP_Project(upload) where ID = ? values (?,?)');

            $statement->bindParam(1, $filename);
            $statement->bindParam(2, $projectID);

            $statement->execute();
```

I hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: no need for where clause inside your insert statement

Comment: *I need to insert 'upload' at a specific 'ID' into my table.*, may be you're trying to perform `UPDATE` operation, not `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MYSQL query you wrote is incorrect. You need the MYSQL UPDATE query for updating the value at a specific column.

```
 $statement = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE PHP_Project SET upload = ? WHERE ID = ?');
```

Check out this tutorial [Mysql update tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much for your very quick and helpful answer! I need to hand it in today :D

Comment: Good luck dude @MatthiasLassnig